# Are there books on algorithms for architecture?

Tags: reference-request, algorithms

I need books on algorithms for organic/nonlinear and linear architect anyone recommend a book?

Comment: I don't really know what you're looking for but the book [Architectural Geometry](http://www.architecturalgeometry.at/) is wonderful.